# OpenURI::HTTPError when use youtube_it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube-data-api

- I had a problem when i tried to use `gem youtube_id` to get video from Youtube.

https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it

And it threw an error same as:

```
OpenURI::HTTPError: 410
from /home/khanhpn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@music/gems/youtube_it-2.4.2/lib/youtube_it/parser.rb:10:in `rescue in initialize'
```

And this is my code:

```
client = YouTubeIt::Client.new(username: "ABC", password: "*****", dev_key: "AI39si74VcEh1_bwetqNaM42qeeCkDFy1ChLshTraxl3d3SXWJHpCRdrI9X68kLFxGki1eWA")
client.videos_by(:top_rated, :time => :today).try(:videos)
```

Hope everybody can explain for me why it didn't run. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Youtube changed its API, I had the same problem with the `link_thumbnailer` gem (https://github.com/gottfrois/link_thumbnailer/issues/60).

There's an issue in the `youtube_it` gem about this, keep an eye on it, they'll probably solve this problem soon: https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it/issues/210